# How do I prevent form resubmission on refresh?

Tags: orchardcms

I found that refreshing a submitted form results in processing the form data again. In some other CMS's I've used, repeated submission pops up a warning (e.g. "You have already submitted this form, are you sure you want to submit it again?").

What's the right way to address such cases in Orchard? I.e. prevent repeated processing of form contents, and/or warn about repeated submission.

Comment: It's generally how browsers work. If you hit refresh, it sends the same request again, which in your case was a form submittance.

Comment: Yes, exactly, but in many circumstances you want to prevent repeated form submission. Techniques include using a nonce hidden input and rejecting forms with already-seen nonces (probably requires server state), using javascript to disable the submit control (hackable on clientside), and redirecting to a different page. I was wondering whether Orchard had a preferred way of dealing with such cases. (We're using redirection now.)

Comment: What form are we talking about? A form you built yourself? A dynamic form built from the admin?
The right way is to redirect after submission.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy, yes, it's a form we built ourselves. Thanks for confirmation regarding redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BertrandLeRoy confirms that redirect after submission is the correct way to handle this case in Orchard. Thanks!